# Waiting posedge clk before doing a job? -- How

Tags: verilog, hdl, system-verilog

```
module DoorControl( clk, data, open,addressOftheMemory,  outp );

localparam Size_ofTheWord = 32;
input open;

input [16:0] addressOftheMemory;
input [Size_ofTheWord-1:0] data;

input clk ;
output reg outp;
reg [WordSize-1: 0] Memory [65535: 0];


always @ ( open )  // open is 1 or 0 
  if ( open  )          
     // i
     outp = Memory[addressOftheMemory];
  else if ( !open )    
     Memory[addressOftheMemory] = data;


endmodule
```

Line marked with (i), I want wait just posedge clk before sending outp to output port.However, When I have tried like ;

```
if ( posedge clk )
```

it gives error

```
while ( clk != 1 ) begin

end
```

it gives absurb answer/simulation output.
**What thing(s) should I put to that line to wait posedge clk before sending output ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delay execution until the clock edge like this:

```
always @ ( open )  // open is 1 or 0 
  if ( open  )
     @(posedge clk) outp = Memory[addressOftheMemory];
  else if ( !open )    
     Memory[addressOftheMemory] = data;
```

That may or may not accomplish what you want. It is not synthesizable, and the `always` block will not be rescheduled while it is executing or suspended, so if `open` toggles multiple times in a clock period, that code is probably not going to do what you want.

More background: you can specify a delay/event control on any statement, including a null statement. (e.g. in `@(posedge clk);`, the semicolon is a null statement.) In fact, the syntax definition of an `always` construct is:

> always_construct: **always** statement

Meaning that there is nothing magical about `always @(open)` or `always @(posedge clk)`, they are simply introducing a statement and specifying event control. When delay control (`#`) is attached to a statement, execution of the statement is deferred until a fixed time in the future. When event control (`@`) is attached to a statement, execution of the statement is deferred until the event condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 3):

You have to think a little more critically about what you are trying to model. It looks like you are just trying to model a memory with "open" controlling the read/write operation.

You have asynchronous writing of data & synchronous reading of data. For memory access it is better just to have complete synchronous behavior.

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
if( open )
    outp = Memory[addressOftheMemory];
else
    Memory[addressOftheMemory] = data;
end
```

Comment: Totally agree. With synchronous logic, the clock is primary.